# Filling Polygon with SVG File so it Will Appear Only One Time in QGIS 3.4.2

Tags: qgis, layers, svg

I have a layer that shows the world, without Antarctica and small islands. 
This layer is made of five different polygons.

[image]

I want to fill it with an SVG file that is displayed non uniform background.

When I create a point layer the SVG background is displayed perfectly.

[image]

However, within the polygon I was unable to display it  properly.

[image]

However I change the Texture width parameters the SVG was not fitting perfectly.
What is needed to be done in order of make it fit?

Comment: is this one single (multipart) polygon?

Comment: Yes it is one single polygon with five rows

Comment: Five rows would mean five polygons.

Comment: As we can see in the screenshot, this shouldn't be a problem. The svg overlaps two or more continents.

Comment: @Nitzan Matan If this is solely for a graphic design purpose, you might be better off exporting your continents as svg and clipping the other svg in Inkscape.

Comment: @NitzanMatan Is this really an image, or is it a vector SVG? If its an image, you could always convert to TIF and georeference to the scale of the earth, then use the polygons as 'inverted polygons' to clip as a pseudo background...